# Excel VB Event RefreshAll is not getting called when sheet is modified using python

Tags: python, pandas, excel, vba, openpyxl

data sheet

[image: data sheet]

data sheet is tied with below VB script

[image: VB Code]

Sheet1 sheet which has pivot table

[image: Sheet1 sheet]

txt_excel.txt

[image: txt_excel.txt file]

I'm trying to update the cell values in my data sheet using a python script. But the RefreshAll event is not getting fired and updating my pivot table in Sheet1 sheet.

Here is the Python script which reads the values from text file and updates data sheet

```py
excel_filepath = "test_excel_file2.xlsm"
txt_filepath = "txt_excel.txt"
data_sheet = "data"
calc_sheet = "Sheet1"

df = pd.read_csv(txt_filepath, sep="|")
print(df)

wb = load_workbook(excel_filepath, keep_vba=True)
ws = wb[data_sheet]
ws.delete_rows(1,ws.max_row)
wb.save(excel_filepath)
ws.active = data_sheet
for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True):
    ws.append(r)
wb.save(excel_filepath)

new_df = pd.read_excel(excel_filepath, sheet_name=None)
print(new_df[calc_sheet])
```

Here the **new_df** variable is not returning the updated value

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Pandas read_excel uses Openpyxl to open/read the file so there is no point after updating the 'data' that the sheet will ever be refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

If you changed your code to something like this then it will work;

Use Xlwings which opens and updates the sheet in EXCEL, this allows for the pivot table to be updated and after saving when read with `pd.read_excel` it will have the update data.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw


excel_filepath = "test_excel_file2.xlsm"
txt_filepath = "txt_excel.txt"
data_sheet = "data"
calc_sheet = "Sheet1"


df = pd.read_csv(txt_filepath, sep="|")
print(df)

with xw.App(visible=True) as app:
    wb = xw.Book(excel_filepath)
    ws = wb.sheets[data_sheet]

    ### Can clear the existing data but its not necessary
    # ws.range("A2:B5").clear_contents()

    ws["A1"].options(pd.DataFrame, header=1, index=False, expand='table').value = df
    wb.save()


new_df = pd.read_excel(excel_filepath, sheet_name=None)
print(new_df[calc_sheet])
```

Console

```
  col  val
0   a   10
1   b    2
2   c    3
3   a   10
    Row Labels  Sum of val
0            a          20
1            b           2
2            c           3
3  Grand Total          25
```

Comment: Can we use xlwings in Linux ?

Comment: Short answer is NO. The requirement here is that the pivot table is updated by the Excel Application by using a module that manipulates an Excel workbook in Excel. Therefore Xlwings requires Excel to be installed so only supports Windows and MACOS. Xlwings does have a PRO version that can work on Linux however that is a 'pay for' release I cannot comment if it would suit this purpose.

Comment: You should be able to use your original code updating the data using Openpyxl then open/close save the workbook in Excel to refresh it. However this still requires opening then save/close the workbook in Excel by whatever method in order to refresh the sheet which negates Linux as an option.